# how to make a x-for/v-for statement and make a block displayed - block

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, alpine.js

I'm trying to change data value false to true in a function and make an x-if/v-if statement in the html template to vissualize the block. The state shanges to true but the blocked isn't showd up at the component. I'm triggering the function with the Search button. So the console is correct.

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-header-xw0exy?file=/index.html

```js
  <head>
    <script
      defer
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section class="content">
        <div
          class="content__top"
          x-data="{
          search: ''
        }"
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            class="input font--m1"
            placeholder="Search for the item"
            x-model="search"
            @keyup.enter="$store.products.getAllProducts(search)"
          />
          <button
            
            @click="$store.products.getAllProducts(search)"
          >
            Search
          </button>
        </div>
        <div >
          <template x-if="showTableHeader">
            <div class="content__mid">
              
            </div>
          </template>
          <div x-data>
            <template x-for="item in $store.products.people" :key="item.id">
              <div >
                <p  x-text="item.name"></p>
                <p  x-text="item.email"></p>
              </div>
            </template>
          </div>
       
    </section>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
        Alpine.store("products", {
          people: [],
          showTableHeader: false,

          getAllProducts(searchInput) {
            fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((res) => {
                this.people = res;

                this.showTableHeader = true; //the line isn't read by the html template

                console.log(this.showTableHeader);
              });
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `showTableHeader` in the `$store.products`, so you need to access it from there:

```
<template x-if="$store.products.showTableHeader">
...
</template>
```